# Conjugation of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $X_{ij}(a) = I_n + a E_{ij}$ be an elementary matrix where $E_{ij}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix that has 1 in position $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else where $a$ is a scalar in some arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$. How can I show that $X_{ij}(a) \in SL(n,\mathbb{F})$ is conjugate to a matrix of the form $X_{12}(b)$?

So this question is asking to show that elementary matrices are similar. I read that two matrices are similar if they have the same eigenvalues. I can show that 1 is the only eigenvalue of $X_{ij}(a)$ and $X_{12}(b)$ if $i \neq j$.

Is this the correct way to proceed or is there a more straightforward approach?

I also proved every matrix in $SL(n, \mathbb{F})$ can be written as a product of elementary matrices but I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: Two matrices with the same eigenvalues need not be similar. The implication goes the other way, and only the other way (i.e. we can only say that, if two matrices are similar, then they have the same eigenvalues).

Answer (score 2):

Hints. Suppose $i\ne j$ and $a\ne0$. You may try to prove that $X_{ij}(a)$ is similar to $X_{12}(a)$ via a permutation matrix, and $X_{12}(a)$ is similar to $X_{12}(1)$ via a diagonal matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't fully understand the second part of your hint.

Comment: @ABC Find a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $DX_{12}(a)D^{-1}=X_{12}(1)$.